# How to remove graft information in mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

I've seen that when using the graft function, the "source" graft revision is displayed in TortoiseHg, together with the other changeset information (user,date, parent, etc..). That it's not always useful, since the source commit could be present only in a local branch, or have been stripped.

Is it possible to remove this information (the commit should just look like the case when a patch has been applied)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source node is added to the metadata of the grafted node and would be part of the hash.  You could `hg export` the node (which doesn't include the graft info), `hg strip` the original node, and `hg import` again.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know all methods to remove graft information from a commit involve recreating the commit. The [import/export suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57983025/3195477) would work fine.

Another approach which might be simpler in some cases would be to just **graft it again** (even starting from the graft commit itself, to a predecessor) but use different options:

[image]

The first 2 checkboxes (use my name and use current date) will make it look like it was a normal commit you just did, and leaving out the third will omit any additional graft details.

The usual caveat applies that if you have already pushed a commit, you generally can't strip it or alter it in any way. (Without a lot of hassle).

Comment: I just tried with your options, but I still see the graft information (not in the commit message but in the metadata). Are you sure that it works for you? Are you using a newer version maybe? I am using hg  4.0 on linux